# Syntax error after show create table in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, create-table

I just want to copy an existing table structure into another database. All queries are executed in phpmyadmin:

I first execute:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE keyword_session
```

Then I execute the output of it in another database:

```
CREATE TABLE `keyword_session` (  
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`session_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And I got the error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Â `session_id` int(11) NOT
>   NULL, Â `keywor' at line 1

Where is the syntax error ? Isn't SHOW CREATE TABLE be a result that you can execute ?

---

**Edit:**
Some information on the system where I try to create the table:

```
Database server :
  Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
  Software: MySQL
  Software version: 5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.10.1 - (Ubuntu)
  Protocol version: 10
  User: ...
  Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
Web server:
  ...
phpMyAdmin:
  Version information: 3.5.1, latest stable version: 3.5.5
  ...
```

Comment: uhmm, your create table statement is working on fiddle, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab087

Comment: `Â session_id int(11) NOT NULL, Â` has unknown symbol `Â` in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error, your statement seems to have unknown symbol **`Â`** in it.

Probably, your new-line feed is misinterpreted. I say so, because it is noticeable at the line ends only:

```
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Â session_id int(11) NOT NULL, Â `keywor
```

notice how the symbol appears before `session_id` and `keyword_id` declaration?

Comment: When I copy-pasted, some strange characters smuggled into the string as spaces. Replacing all spaces/newlines fixed the problem.

Comment: And this probably was because of UTF-8 and other text format conversions. Happens a lot with me when I port stuff b/w linux and Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
show create table table_name;
```

retrieves the information from the database **information_schema** which has the default character set collation **utf8_general_ci**

so the data will be stored with that characters specifically

when you type the same manually then you won't get the error

As shown in the Error your statement has unknown symbol Â which belongs to default character set

More information on the character set and collation can be found [here](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_general_ci.european.html) which is the best  one to refer to understand them to avoid or to solve the future errors

Answer (score 0):

Beware of the new versions of phpmyadmin with online editing. Sometimes copying from those text-boxes can give you strange characters.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste it into notepad or a text editor, then try and repaste it.  You probably have some garbage characters in there.